# Base 64 encode or binary?

Tags: javascript, php

Which is better to send an image to a server via AJAX?

*Send the binary of the file*

or

*Base 64 encode the string?*

Comment: Well, would you have a reason to base64 encode it? Is binary being trampled in transport?

Comment: I dont know that's why Im asking

Comment: why would somebody load an image via ajax?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better explaining what you are trying to do, or what problem you are encountering. What lead you to this question?

Comment: @Cristoph e.g. upload a signature made on a touchdevice from an phonegap app and display a notification if successful. 

There are many valid usecases to send an image via ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 increases the filesize of any data passed into it (~33%), and adds overhead because you'll need to encode it on one end and decode it on another.

Generally, when a file is being sent the most 'mangling' it will receive is compression of some type (typically GZIP); this will not actually 'damage' the file though because the server/browser know to unpack it before it reaches the other end.

If the concern is for ensuring the integrity of the file, NOT performing extra operations is the way to go, even though *technically* nothing bad should happen performing those steps, it's just one more potential failure point.

Use the KISS principle; send the raw image as-is and don't include extra steps.

Edit: corrected filesize increase. Again. Added more info.

Comment: it's 33%: 3 binary chars become 4 base64 chars.